# Jquery on BUTTON

Tags: jquery

How do i set up the "ON" method to undo when the button has been clicked again. So a ON & OFF BUTTON.

```
 $('#videoNest span').on('click', function(e) {

    First Time Clicked
    //// ON

       $('<div class="off-overlay"></div>').insertAfter('#container');

           $('#example_video_1').addClass("light-grad");

    Second Time Clicked
    ///// OFF 

       remove div off-overlay $('<div class="off-overlay"></div>').insertAfter('#container');

         remove class  $('#example_video_1').addClass("light-grad");

    });


    });
```

Comment: Do u want to make click only once..

Answer (score 2):

After first click unbind the click and bind to new OFF event . Do the same in OFF method

```
         $(this).unbind("click");
         $(this).on("click",function() { OFFFunction(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a boolean variable and set it to true = on and false = off and change it inside an if statement, so like:

```
if (boolean == true){
    // do stuff
    boolean = false
} else if (boolean == false) {
    // do stuff
    boolean = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below

**[live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/EBHbN/1/)**

```
$("#toggle_button").click(function(){
    if($("#OnOffDiv").hasClass("On"))
    {
        $("#OnOffDiv").removeClass("On");
        $("#OnOffDiv").addClass("Off");
        $("#OnOffDiv").html("OFF");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#OnOffDiv").removeClass("Off");
        $("#OnOffDiv").addClass("On");
        $("#OnOffDiv").html("ON");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWC9w/)

It might not resemeble exactly with you requirements, you have to change it . Just get the idea from it.

```
$('#videoNest span').on('click',function(){
    var flg =$('#example_video_1').hasClass("light-grad");

    $("#container +.off-overlay").toggle('slow',function(){
      if(flg)$('#example_video_1').removeClass("light-grad")         
      else $('#example_video_1').addClass("light-grad")         
    });     
});
```

given html:

```
<div id="videoNest">
    <span>Toggle</span>
    <div id="container">Container</div>
    <div class="off-overlay">overlay</div>
    <div id="example_video_1" > example_video_1 </div>
</div>
```